# Jquery Changing Video source Src not having the desired affect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to dynamically change the src file of a video element on my page, however when I change the source it does not seem to effect the video at all.

I can even delete the video source element in the browser and the video still keeps chugging along as if nothing has happened to it.

Am I misunderstanding the video element?

Thanks

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wh1pwzm6/3/

Html

```
<video id="video-10" width="300px" videoid="2" class="text-left  video-content  fadeIn wow animated" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" animationid="8" style="animation-duration: 5s; visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;">
    <source id="src-video-10" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JQuery

```
var newfile = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";

$("#src-video-10").attr('src',newfile);
```

Edit, thanks to guest271314 for the answer, edited the answer below

```
var newfile = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";


var video = $("#video-10")[0];
video.pause();
$("#src-video-10").attr('src',newfile);
video.load();
video.play();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, you are selecting `video` `src`, though using `source` element ?

Try calling `.load()` then `.play()` on `video` element after setting `source` `src`

```
var video = $("#video-10");
video.find("source").attr("src", newfile);
video.get().load();
video.get().play();
```

Comment: I just tried  var video = $("#video-10"); video.get().load();             video.get().play(); after I replaced the file name but I get "Uncaught TypeError: video.get(...).load is not a function"

Comment: @Hopeless Yes, not certain why `video` is not being displayed at jsfiddle ? Try jsfiddle with `http:` protocol, as request for video `src` is `http:`

Comment: @ guest271314 Oh can you not see the video at all?

Comment: @Hopeless Added `controls` attribute for `controls` to be visisble

Comment: I tried    var video = $("#video-10",iframe.contents());                  video.pause();   but I get     Uncaught TypeError: video.pause is not a function

Comment: Request for `"http://www.davidfoley.co.uk/Barbaric/resources/wobblingegg.mp4"` is returning status code `206 Partial Content` with `Content-Length:1` . When tried using `XMLHttpRequest` received `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.davidfoley.co.uk/Barbaric/resources/wobblingegg.mp4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` The issue appears to be the response from the `url`

Comment: Odd not sure what that is, I've changed the video sources to ones I found on W3C instead of my own so hopefully that error will not appear not, new demo at https://jsfiddle.net/wh1pwzm6/3/

Comment: @Hopeless `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` , `VM118:57 GET https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` Will try to put together a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what that error is all about, i'm on Chrome and i've tried the jsfiddle or 2 pcs and both seem to be displaying it correctly

Comment: _"i've tried the jsfiddle or 2 pcs and both seem to be displaying it correctly"_   Is `js` at post returning expected results, save for error trying to call `.pause()` on jQuery object ? _"I tried the above code and got
Uncaught TypeError: video.pause is not a function"_ You are getting error because `$("#video-10");` is a jQuery object, not `DOM` element; `DOM` element `video` or should have those methods. Try `var video = $("#video-10")[0];` or `var video = $("#video-10").get()` , then call `video.pause()`, `video.load()` , `video.play()`

Comment: Aha! That did the trick! https://jsfiddle.net/wh1pwzm6/4/   Thanks very much!!! <3 Will marked an answer! :D